# Задача на наследование C#

Tags: c#

Создать такую иерархию классов A, B и C, чтобы код ниже компилировался и выводил текст "ABC"

```
static void Main(string[] args)  
{  
    var b = new B(); 
    var c = new C();  
    ((A)c).PrintMessage();  
    ((A)b).PrintMessage();  
    c.PrintMessage();  
}
```

Подскажите как правильно построить наследование, а то постоянно ловлю

> System.InvalidCastException

Comment: Добавьте наработки, даже если они не рабочие :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://ideone.com/cUNAkG

```
class A      { public        virtual  void PrintMessage() { Console.Write("A"); } }
class B : A  { public sealed override void PrintMessage() { Console.Write("B"); } }
class C : A  { public new             void PrintMessage() { Console.Write("C"); } }
```

Comment: а sealed зачем?

Comment: @Grundy, перестарался. У меня сначала было `C:B`, но потом я понял, что накосячил. А sealed остался.

Answer (score 0):

```
class B : A { ... }
class C : A { ... }
```

В декларациях методов `PrintMessage` в классах `A`, `B` и `C` Вам нужно будет использовать ключевые слова `virtual`, `override` и `new` соответственно.